# Cordova app crashes after splash screen with targetsdk 29

Tags: cordova, crosswalk, target-sdk

In order to meet Google requirements I switched the targetsdk version to 29 on my Cordova app (that uses xwalk 2.4.0). After the update the app crashes when starts: I've found  the following errors in logcat:

```
11-02 19:13:46.079 28309 28451 W chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app/com.visitami.visitamiprof-kerC1tXroImpS9vWnzWF_w==/lib/arm64/libxwalkdummy.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
11-02 19:13:46.079 28309 28451 W chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(406)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app/com.visitami.visitamiprof-kerC1tXroImpS9vWnzWF_w==/lib/arm64/libxwalkdummy.so
11-02 19:13:46.080 28309 28451 W chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app/com.visitami.visitamiprof-kerC1tXroImpS9vWnzWF_w==/lib/arm64/libxwalkcore.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
11-02 19:13:46.081 28309 28451 W chromium: [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(406)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app/com.visitami.visitamiprof-kerC1tXroImpS9vWnzWF_w==/lib/arm64/libxwalkcore.so
11-02 19:13:46.084  4948  7255 V WindowManager: Relayout Window{584e4ba u0 com.visitami.visitamiprof/com.visitami.visitamiprof.Visitami}: viewVisibility=0 req=1440x2960
```

and then:

```
1-02 19:13:49.040 26554 28485 D AppErrorNotification: errorType : 24, process : com.visitami.visitamiprof , uid : 0
11-02 19:13:49.134  4948  5181 W InputDispatcher: channel '584e4ba com.visitami.visitamiprof/com.visitami.visitamiprof.Visitami (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=566
11-02 19:13:49.134  4948  5181 E InputDispatcher: channel '584e4ba com.visitami.visitamiprof/com.visitami.visitamiprof.Visitami (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-02 19:13:49.134  4948  5181 W InputDispatcher: channel '96fbcdc com.visitami.visitamiprof/com.visitami.visitamiprof.Visitami (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=558
11-02 19:13:49.134  4948  5181 E InputDispatcher: channel '96fbcdc com.visitami.visitamiprof/com.visitami.visitamiprof.Visitami (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-02 19:13:49.138  4948  5181 W InputDispatcher: channel 'f7c6c29 com.visitami.visitamiprof/com.visitami.visitamiprof.Visitami (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9, fd=516
11-02 19:13:49.138  4948  5181 E InputDispatcher: channel 'f7c6c29 com.visitami.visitamiprof/com.visitami.visitamiprof.Visitami (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

For my app, removing xwalk is a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat older question, but I have 'one' answer that may work for someone else.

We had the same issue and could not get the app to work at all.
In the end I removed xwalk just for testing purposes and it worked.

Not only did the app still work properly after testing on Android 5 and 11, but the APK went from 75MB to 4MB.
The APK also does not include any more '.so' files, so the store will not complain about architecture any more.

I guess it depends on if you need the extra features that xwalk offered, e.g. CSS3